# Circuit Breaker for an orchestrator

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have a facade which calls 3 different services for some type of requests and finally orchestrates the responses before sending the response back to the client. Here, it is mandatory that all 3 services are up and serving as expected. The client request can not be served even one of them is down. 
  I am looking for a circuit breaker to solve this problem. The circuit breaker should respond with error code even one of the service is down. I was checking the resilence4j circuit breaker and it doesnt fit for my problem.

https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker

Is there any other open source available?

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it fit to you problem?
You can protect every service with a CircuitBreaker. As soon one of the CircuitBreakers is open, you can short circuit and directly return an error response to your client.

Answer (score 0):

`CircuitBreaker` Works on protected function as below –

**Thread <—> CircuitBreaker <—> Protected_Function**

So a `Protected_Function` can call 1 or more microservices, Mostly we use 1 `Protected_Function` for 1 external micro service call because we have can tune resilience based on the profile or behavior of that particular micro-service. But as your requirement is different so we can have 3 calls under 1 `Protected_Function`.

So as per your explanation above, you Façade is calling 3 micro-services (assume in series). What you can do is to call you Façade or all 3 services through or inside a Protected Function –

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "OVERALL_PROTECTION")
public Your_Response  Protected_Function  (Your_Request) {
        Call_To_Service_1;
        Call_To_Service_2;
        Call_To_Service_3;
        return Orchestrate_Your_Response;
}
```

Further you can add resilience for `OVERALL_PROTECTION` in your YAML property file as below (I have used Count based Sliding Window) –

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  backends:
    OVERALL_PROTECTION:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 100                     # start rate calc after 100 calls
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 100                  # minimum calls before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate.
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 10  # number of permitted calls when the CircuitBreaker is half open
      waitDurationInOpenState: 10s               # time that the CircuitBreaker should wait before transitioning from open to half-open
      failureRateThreshold: 50                   # failure rate threshold in percentage
      slowCallRateThreshold: 100                 # consider all transactions under interceptor for slow call rate
      slowCallDurationThreshold: 2s              # if a call is taking more than 2s then increase the error rate
      recordExceptions:                          # increment error rate if following exception occurs
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
        - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
```

You can also use time based `slidingWindow` instead of count based if you wish, Rest I have mentioned #Comment for self explanation in front of each parameter in configuration.

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    OVERALL_PROTECTION:
      maxRetryAttempts: 5
      waitDuration: 100
      retryExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
        - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
```

Above configuration will perform a retry for 5 times if Exceptions under `retryExceptions` occurs.

```
resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  instances:
    OVERALL_PROTECTION:
       timeoutDuration: 100ms                  #The default wait time a thread waits for a permission
       limitRefreshPeriod: 1000                #The period of a limit refresh. After each period the rate limiter sets its permissions count back to the limitForPeriod value
       limitForPeriod: 25                      #The number of permissions available during one limit refresh period
```

Above configuration will allow maximum up to 25 transactions in 1 second.